# How can I determine classes in k-nn

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, knn

My problem is as follows: I have one unknown value and two classes. I calculate the distances from an unknown value to every known value, and I make one matrix. But now I have to take the three smallest distances and I must determine their class, and I don't know how I can take these three values and determine their class and show it to the user

here is my code;

```
clc

clear;

clear all;

A=[1 2; 2 2; 1.5 3; 3 4];

B=[4 5; 7 5; 7 6; 9 7];

k=3;

x1=input('pls enter x ');

y1=input('pls enter y ');

for i=1:1:4

xa=A(i,1);

ya=A(i,2);

 da=sqrt((x1-xa)^2+(y1-ya)^2);

 for h=1:length(da)

danew(i)=da(h);

 end


end

danew

for j=1:1:4

xb=B(j,1);

yb=B(j,2);

 db=sqrt((x1-xb)^2+(y1-yb)^2);

for m=1:length(db)

dbnew(j)=db(m);

end


 end

dbnew 

dd=[danew dbnew]

for p=1:length(dd)

for r=length(dd):-1:1+p

    if dd(r)<dd(r-1);

        gecici=dd(r-1);

        dd(r-1)=dd(r);

        dd(r)=gecici;
    end

end


end

dd
```

Comment: I remember fixing the formatting of this same exact question two days ago. Did you delete the question and post it anew? This is not acceptable behavior. If you don’t get answers, improve your question. The same one will not get any more attention anyway.